# New 2013 Workflows won't start. Existing will

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I am using SharePoint 2013 on Premise with SharePoint designer 2013.

I have several 2013 Workflows which work fine. However, new 2013 Workflows do not initate. I have checked to ensure all run after new item is created.

I create a new test workflow using 2010 Workflows which does work.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add the screen shot of your working settings page from SharePoint designer?

Comment: Does the workflow work when you trigger it manually?

Comment: Hi Harshal. No it comes up with an error saying the workflow could not be started.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot your issue as following:

If the workflow works well when you start the workflow manually? Make sure you have not used System Account to create the items and trigger the workflow.

If so, you can use another account or add all the action in the workflow to App Step and check again.

Try to republish the workflow and check again.